# Tensorflow asking to run the build even though it is done

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

As always, tensorflow the weird dumb framework is going unintuitive haywire piece of crap on me. Can someone please be kind enough to help me out with this? I am able to run the checkpointing (how much of a mess can saving a model be? leave it to tensorflow to make a mountain out of a molehill) [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint) as given on the tutorial page, but, dare i make a little modification here a little modification there. The sticks and stones contraption called tensorflow comes crumbling down.

As you can clearly see i am running the build method but i am getting the error that i must run the build method with an input shape. In tutorial the build method is not there at all and the one layer `self.l1` is built in the `__init__` itself which, they themselves advice against at several other places

```
class Net(tf.keras.Model):
  """A simple linear model."""

  def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    #self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
  def build(self,input_shape):
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
    self.dummy = tf.Variable(trainable=True,initial_value=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()(shape=input_shape,dtype=tf.float32))
    print('built layers')
  def call(self, x):
    return self.l1(x)

net = Net()
net.build([1,])
net.save_weights('easy_checkpoint')
```

The output and trace i am getting is:

```
built layers
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-3b54dc506ffd> in <module>
      1 net = Net()
      2 net.build([1,])
----> 3 net.save_weights('easy_checkpoint')

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite, save_format)
   1111         ValueError: For invalid/unknown format arguments.
   1112     """
-> 1113     self._assert_weights_created()
   1114     filepath_is_h5 = _is_hdf5_filepath(filepath)
   1115     if save_format is None:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _assert_weights_created(self)
   1560                        'Weights are created when the Model is first called on '
   1561                        'inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.' %
-> 1562                        self.name)
   1563 
   1564   def _graph_network_add_loss(self, symbolic_loss):

ValueError: Weights for model net_10 have not yet been created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.
```

Edit: Here is my hunch: The problem with my code is that the build does not execute the build of `self.l1` but just creates it. Things do work out fine if i add `self.l1` creation in `__init__` and call `super().__build__()` as the first line in Net's build. Things make sense so far but, the code fails again if i replace `super().build(input_shape)` with `self.l1.build(input_shape)`. Also, the code belows shows that all the variables are actually there. So, i am lost again. Any help is much appreciated

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)
class Net1(tf.keras.Model):
  """A simple linear model."""
  def __init__(self):
    super(Net1, self).__init__()
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
  def build(self,input_shape):
    super().build(input_shape)
    self.dummy = tf.Variable(trainable=True,initial_value=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.float32))
    print(self.variables)
  def call(self, x):
    return self.l1(x)

net = Net1()
net.build((10,1))
print('*'*50)
print(net.variables)

output:
[<tf.Variable 'dense_56/kernel:0' shape=(1, 5) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3291242 , -0.11798644, -0.294235  , -0.07103491, -0.9326792 ]],
      dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_56/bias:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.09575049], dtype=float32)>]
**************************************************
[<tf.Variable 'dense_56/kernel:0' shape=(1, 5) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3291242 , -0.11798644, -0.294235  , -0.07103491, -0.9326792 ]],
      dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_56/bias:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.09575049], dtype=float32)>]
```

whereas,

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)
class Net1(tf.keras.Model):
  """A simple linear model."""

  def __init__(self):
    super(Net1, self).__init__()
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
  def build(self,input_shape):
    self.l1.build(input_shape)
    self.dummy = tf.Variable(trainable=True,initial_value=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.float32))
    print('variables',self.l1.variables,self.dummy)
  def call(self, x):
    return self.l1(x)

net = Net1()
net.build((10,1))
print(net.variables)

output:
variables [<tf.Variable 'kernel:0' shape=(1, 5) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3291242 , -0.11798644, -0.294235  , -0.07103491, -0.9326792 ]],
      dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'bias:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>] <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.09575049], dtype=float32)>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-35561efcdc2f> in <module>
     15 net = Net1()
     16 net.build((10,1))
---> 17 print(net.variables)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in variables(self)
   1965       A list of variables.
   1966     """
-> 1967     return self.weights
   1968 
   1969   @property

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in weights(self)
    498       A list of variables.
    499     """
--> 500     return self._dedup_weights(self._undeduplicated_weights)
    501 
    502   @property

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _undeduplicated_weights(self)
    503   def _undeduplicated_weights(self):
    504     """Returns the undeduplicated list of all layer variables/weights."""
--> 505     self._assert_weights_created()
    506     weights = []
    507     for layer in self._layers:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _assert_weights_created(self)
   1560                        'Weights are created when the Model is first called on '
   1561                        'inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.' %
-> 1562                        self.name)
   1563 
   1564   def _graph_network_add_loss(self, symbolic_loss):

ValueError: Weights for model net1_40 have not yet been created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.
```

Answer (score 1):

TL/DR: This is not a problem with `save_weight` method. In order to build a subclassed model, you need to run the subclassed model on a real input. I only added two lines to the end of your code as shown below.

```
#net.build(input_shape=[1,]) # don't need it. When you call the model with real input, `build` method will be executed
x_train = tf.random.normal(shape=(100,1),dtype=tf.float32)
output=net.predict(x_train)
```

Please check below for more details.

```
import tensorflow as tf
class Net(tf.keras.Model):
  """A simple linear model."""

  def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    #self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
  def build(self,input_shape):
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
    self.dummy = tf.Variable(trainable=True,initial_value=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.float32))
    print('built layers')
  def call(self, x):
    return self.l1(x)

net = Net()
#net.build(input_shape=[1,]) # don't need it. When you call the model with real input, `build` method will be executed
x_train = tf.random.normal(shape=(100,1),dtype=tf.float32)
output=net.predict(x_train)
net.save_weights('easy_checkpoint')
```

A subclassed model is a piece of Python code (a call method). There is no graph of layers here. We cannot know how layers are connected to each other (because that's defined in the body of call, not as an explicit data structure), so we cannot infer input / output shapes. You can try printing `model.summary` after instantiating the subclass model. It will throw same error as you reported.

In contrast to subclassed models, You can do all these things (printing summary, input / output shapes) in a Functional or Sequential model because these models are static graphs of layers.

With that simple modification, your code is working as expected. I can print the weights, shapes etc., and can save weights also.

Comment: I guess running the model runs it's build method and that is what is supposed to solve the issue. Which i am doing explicitly. So i dont know what running the model once solves. Even though it does solve the problem i dont know why of it.

Comment: Agree. It's build method builds the layers but layers are not connected in the sense that you cannot do shape inference. which means shape of second and subsequent layers are unknown to the model so it can not instantiate weights accordingly. So we need to call the model with a data (single data is enough for shape inference and weights initiation).  check for more details here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#saving_loading_only_the_models_weights_values

Comment: build takes in an input_shape argument

Comment: please check the edited question. Many thanks for helping me in advance sir!

Comment: Agree, it take `input_shape` as an argument. But to create weights, we need to execute `call` method. So, we need to call the model on a single data or run `model.predict` on single data. One more thing you need to note is when you want to load, you need to instantiate the subcalssed model, run it on single data to create random weights, then load the saved_weights by using `load_weights` method.

Comment: Call calls the build the first time it is run. One does not need to run the call method explicitly. Please check the edit in question